# Should I use meta tags or JSON-LD?

Tags: seo, meta-tags, json-ld

As I'm new to the SEO, can someone guide me regarding meta tags and JSON-LD?

I mean to say that can I use only JSON-LD to specify all the meta attributes required by a search engine or should I use both, meta tags to define the page meta attributes and JSON-LD for structured data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I use Meta Tags or Json-LD?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/114842/should-i-use-meta-tags-or-json-ld)

Comment: This is the second time you have asked this question.  The first time, your question was closed.   Rather than delete the question and re-ask it, you are expected to edit your closed question to improve it.

Comment: If you are new to SEO, you shouldn't even be thinking about JSON-LD.  Structured data doesn't help SEO much.  It doesn't help rankings or improve indexing.  All it does is give you special display in the search results for some very specific types of content.   Start doing SEO with site crawlability, creating good content, and basic keyword optimization.

Comment: Exactly sir, that is what I did. I edited it and even specified it to the moderator that I have made the necessary correction and limited the question to only one but "On-hold" didn't got removed. Apart from that, thanks for your advice and I'm willing to accept your solution. I also think that being a natural player and working with basic SEO will work and atleast will make me learn things in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

> Meta tags to define the Page meta and Json-ld for structured data

Exactly, use title and description with regular HTML tags and insert structured data using json-ld. You can this with Google Tag manager as well, there are plenty of guides that show how to do this:

[Titles and descriptions using GTM](https://www.lunametrics.com/labs/recipes/seo-titles-and-descriptions/)

[How to add schema markup to your site using Google Tag Manager](https://searchengineland.com/add-schema-markup-site-using-google-tag-manager-272516)